# ¿Son aceptables las preguntas que en Inglés corresponderian a Programmers StackExchange?

Tags: discusión

En la comunidad de habla inglesa existen varias comunidades sobre programación, StackOverflow que cubre todo lo que tiene que ver con implementación y Programmers que cubre lo demás. (Visión simplificada ya que hay más comunidades que cubren de alguna forma la ciencia de la computación/programación)

Ante la ausencia de un Programmers en español, ¿Se deberian considerar las preguntas de Programmers como parte de StackOverflow en español?

Comment: creo que por ahi se hablo sobre algo de la posibilidad de incluir temas en esSO por ejemplo los que usted menciona, por falta de un lugar para ello pero no se como queda la cosa si te interesa creo que estara en los primeros meta y creo que fue juan quien responde o pregunta algo si lo veo te dejo el link saludos

Comment: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/stack-overflow-en-espa%C3%B1ol-funcionar%C3%A1-exactamente-como-stack-overflow creo que es este

Comment: Sí, y ahora la pregunta es si lo que normalmente se pregunta en Programmers Stack Exchange se consideracomo apropiado para esta comunidad. C:

Comment: no te sabria responder mejor deja un mensaje en el chat saludos

Comment: Al menos que propongan un Programmers SE en español y dure en aprobación tres años al igual que este ;)

Comment: Hace unos meses fue cerrada una propuesta en area51, era Programmers SE en español; con el argumento de que "intenta drenar audiencia de otro sitio". No tengo el link por que lo borraron, pero claramente se referia a este sitio. Asi que la respuesta es SI, StackExchange quiere un unico sito de programacion en español, la menos por ahora.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yo propongo que

### SÍ

aceptemos estas preguntas. Programmers y Stack Overflow tienen temas muy similares, y ambos son interesantes para programadores.

1. Por ahora, el equipo de Stack Overflow no tiene ganas de aceptar sitios en idiomas diferentes del inglés, especialmente sitios diferentes de Stack Overflow, y no aceptarán propuestas como Programadores en español ([Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) fue una excepción.) Así que no tiene sentido esperar un sitio separado para estas preguntas.

   > [Unfortunately, we are not currently accepting proposals for non-English sites — See Internationalization 'State of the Stack' – Robert Cartaino♦ Nov 22 at 3:26](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german)
2. Nuestra comunidad es más pequeña que la del SO inglés, y creo que siempre va a ser así. Ellos tienen millones de usuarios y miles de preguntas cada día, y por eso necesitan reglas estrictas para mantener la calidad del sitio. Nosotros no tenemos los problemas de una comunidad muy grande, entonces podemos ser mas abiertos.
3. Otras comunidades de Stack Overflow ya han decidido tener un alcance más amplio. [Stack Overflow en ruso acepta las preguntas](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1762/176684) que en inglés corresponderían a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), y [Stack Overflow en japonés acepta las preguntas](https://meta.superuser.com/a/9187/78666) que corresponderían a [Super User](https://superuser.com/) ([pero Stack Overflow en portugués no las acepta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2547/909)). Nosotros también podemos definir nuestras proprias reglas.

**Pero**, necesitamos tener cuidado de no aceptar preguntas que no sean útiles. [El FAQ de Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) define qué temas aceptan, y cuales no:

> Pregunta sobre...
>
> - Requisitos de software
> - Arquitectura y diseño de software
> - Algoritmos y estructuras de datos
> - Metodologías y procesos de desarrollo
> - Gestión de la ingeniería de software
> - Aseguramiento de la calidad y pruebas
> - Licencias de software
>
> No preguntes sobre...
>
> - Cuestiones laborales generales, orientación profesional, búsqueda de empleo, salario o compensación
> - <s>Cuestiones de implementación y herramientas de codificación</s> [*Stack Overflow tiene que aceptar estas preguntas*]
> - Qué debes aprender a continuación
> - Qué proyectos debes hacer o qué libros debes leer
> - Dónde se puede encontrar bibliotecas, herramientas, recursos, u otras
>   recomendaciones de productos / servicios
> - Actividades de vida personal o no de programación
> - Preguntas que se basan principalmente en opiniones
> - Preguntas con demasiadas respuestas posibles o que requerirían una respuesta muy extensa

Comment: Mientras no exista un sitio en español estilo code review estoy de acuerdo. Si es que algún dia se llegara a implementar habría que cambiar esta política.

Comment: Primero consolidemos el sitio sobre el tema medular. Luego consideremos incluir otros temas.

Comment: Hay lugar aquí para ese tipo de preguntas pero como se ha mencionado, llenemos el sitio primero con preguntas sobre nuestro tema modular.  Esto no quiere decir que no debamos preguntar algo al estilo Code Review hasta que tengamos "X" preguntas en total - solamente que nuestro enfoque debe ser otro al comenzar.  Se vale la diversidad de preguntas siendo que tenemos un sitio nada mas.

Answer (score 4):

Yo diría que **sí**, por las razones que menciona Peter Olson (y también me gusta la idea de aceptar preguntas de tipo Code Review). Que en el sitio en inglés no se admitan tales preguntas no implica automáticamente que nosotros no debamos hacerlo. Tenemos que construir nuestra propia comunidad.

Dicho esto, no creo que haga falta organizar una encuesta o similar para decidir eso (aunque está muy bien debatirlo); serán los votos positivos o negativos de los usuarios (y los reportes) los que vayan modelando cuál es el contenido más apropiado para el sitio.

Comment: Pero los usuarios no saben usar los votos. En caso de que algo este fuera de tema se tiene que votar para cerrar. Los votos negativos es para información errónea o de baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Ahora no.

## Explicación

Durante la beta privada y la beta pública nos debemos enfocar a consolidar el sitio alrededor del tema medular del sitio. Una vez que el sitio esté consolidado se podría retomar el tema.

Answer (score -3):

## NO

[image: Descripción Programmers SE]

> es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para los profesionales y los estudiantes
>   de desarrollo de software y otros temas relacionados, que estén interesados
>   en obtener respuestas de expertos **sobre temas conceptuales** de desarrollo

Y citando a **[Help > On-Topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**:

> - requerimientos de software
> - arquitectura y diseño de software
> - conceptos de algoritmos y la estructuras de datos
> - aseguramiento de la calidad y testing
> - metodologías y procesos de desarrollo
> - gestión de configuración de software
> - gestión de la ingeniería de software
> - licenciamiento de software

---

Desde mi punto de vista es sencillo: sabemos de qué se trata Stack Overflow... **código**.

Es claro, puntual y conciso. Y es lo que para mí lo hace interesante.

Ahora bien, por supuesto que hay temas que podrían entrar en uno o en el otro, pero la visión es distinta porque la comunidad de cada uno es distinta. Personalmente no me preocuparía por lo que hacen los demás, sino en lo que se hace en Stack Overflow en español, citando a "[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)":

- un problema específico de programación
- un algoritmo de software
- herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores
- y es un problema **práctico**, que **tiene respuesta** y único al desarrollo de software

---

De lo contrario, perfectamente pueden iniciar una propuesta en [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No te estas contradiciendo "sabemos de qué se trata Stack Overflow... código." con "Personalmente no me preocuparía por lo que hacen los demás, sino en lo que se hace en Stack Overflow en español."?

Finalmente esta discusion es si seria bueno para la comunidad abarcar temas que normalmente abarca Programmers.

Comment: Adicionalmente, lo que dice este sitio en su descripcion es: "Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores."

Comment: "*sino en lo que se hace en Stack Overflow en español*" me refiero a seguir sumando contenido, dedicarnos a que marche sobre ruedas... Y mi respuesta a si deberíamos incluir otros temas es claramente no... en mi opinión debería ser sobre código, no temas conceptuales.

Comment: @Fabián tenés razón en que la descripción es genérica... voy a agregar los temas que se tratan para diferenciarlo. Para mí está clara la diferencia, quizás con eso lo explico mejor.

Comment: Ahora, porque no? Digo, yo no quiero ver cosas sobre iOS, XCode C# o muchos otros temas que no son de mi interes pero sí de otros. (Ya estan como tags ignorados)

Comment: Perdon, el comentario que acbao de borrar habia leido mal tu respuesta. Pero sí; busco que se incluyan esos temas en SOes.

Comment: @Fabián Me parece totalmente válida tu postura, y una muy buena pregunta... por eso puse mi respuesta: está claro que opinamos diferente.

Comment: Sí, y finalmente estare cuestionando lo que surja.(No estoy de acuerdo contigo pero es una buena contribucion a la discusión.)

Comment: @Fabián Para eso está meta! Deberías ponerme -1 si no estás de acuerdo (corresponde).

Comment: No, yo considero que los -1 es solo si es una mala aportacion.(IE, incorrecto, spam, etc) Tu punto como lo presentastes es correcto; pero no estoy de acuerdo con esa vision.

Comment: Finalmente, y especialmente en meta, tiene que estar abierto a haber diferentes puntos de vista/visiones que no todos esten de acuerdo pero se puedan plantear y discutir.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, la diferencia entre conceptos y herramientas no es tan rígida como muchos lo ven.  Dicté unos cursillos sobre un DBMS hace como 30 años.  Y antes de presentar los detalles de la herramienta, convenía presentar los conceptos básicos de lo que es una base de datos y cómo añade valor.

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel: meta funciona de otra manera. Si te fijas, la reputación de un usuario en meta es su reputación en el sitio asociado, y los votos en meta no afectan a la reputación. Esto es intencionado. Los votos tienen un significado distinto en meta: significan "de acuerdo" o "en desacuerdo". Otra cosa específica de meta es que se espera que haya muchas respuestas, y la comunidad las vote. En cambio, en los sitios asociados no se esperan muchas respuestas, ya que se supone que las preguntas deben poder responderse objetivamente.

Comment: Esto es, el sitio principal se supone que trata temas "objectivos", y meta puede tratar temas "subjetivos".