# ¿Son aceptables las preguntas conceptuales?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Preguntas sobre conceptos de programación; Ejemplo: [¿Qué es una mónada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150/qu%C3%A9-es-una-m%C3%B3nada)

Primero que nada:

1. Tiene una unica respuesta correcta no subjetiva. (El concepto de mónada tiene una unica definición)
2. No conflictua con los ejemplos de malas preguntas definidas en Area 51 ( https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish?page=2&tab=votes&phase=definition#tab-top ) Unicamente dos?
3. Hay una pregunta equivalente en el StackOverflow en Ingles( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad ), que fue protegida contra malas respuestas de nuevos usuarios pero no cerrada y mantenida por razones historicas como otras preguntas que consideraron fuera de lugar posteriormente.( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read )
4. Es de utilidad para los que quieran programar Funcionalmente/Con Mónadas. (Haskell por ejemplo)

Y el porque abrí esta discusión:

1. Ya se cerro
2. Ya se reabrio
3. Ahora alguien más la quiere volver a cerrar

Relacionado: [¿Son aceptables las preguntas que en Inglés corresponderian a Programmers StackExchange?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/109/son-aceptables-las-preguntas-que-en-ingl%C3%A9s-corresponderian-a-programmers-stacke) (Incluye conceptuales)

Comment: absolutamente si, o queremos que la gente leea wikipedia? somos StackOverflow. deberian por cierto estar bien planteadas pero no somos SO en ingles, en ingles hay mucha documentacion muy buena. En español lamentablemente no.

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109/son-aceptables-las-preguntas-que-en-ingl%C3%A9s-corresponderian-a-programmers-stacke

Comment: Yo votaría por volver este tipo de respuestas "community wiki", la pregunta relacionada de enSO está así.

Comment: Otro ejemplo similar, se cerro, se reabrio y se esta por volver a cerrar :) que chistoso. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352/que-consideraciones-deber%c3%ada-tener-en-cuenta-antes-de-incluir-una-librer%c3%ada-open

Answer (score 6):

## Respuesta corta

Las preguntas sobre definiciones deben cerrarse debido a que no corresponden a los temas a tratar en el sitio principal.

## Explicación

Al ejemplo provisto, si bien podría llamársele pregunta conceptual, de esta categoría corresponde a un subtipo más específico que es el de definición. Este tipo de preguntas no están incluidas en el alcance descrito en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

La justificación histórica a la que se hace referencia podría deberse a que se permitían dichas preguntas en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés cuando fueron publicadas originalmente o alguna otra razón pero se trata de una excepción y no deberían aplicarse estas excepciones durante la beta privada.

Una situación que podría ser diferente es una pregunta conceptual que esté relacionada con un problema real concreto y preferentemente complejo. Me parece que un caso de esto podría ser la desambiguación de conceptos así como los conceptos complejos que requiriese de un discernimiento que no es sencillo de lograr con la lectura de un artículo enciclopédico o libro de texto.

Cabe resaltar que los problemas hipotéticos corresponden a foros de discusión, libros de texto, entre otro tipo de espacios pero no a Stack Overflow.

Comment: ¿Y qué se hace con este tipo de preguntas? En SO podrían migrarse a *Computer Science SE* o a *Programmers SE*, pero no tenermos de eso en español...

Answer (score 3):

La [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) relacionada de enSO es una "Community wiki", pienso que esta pregunta que es buena pero muy genérica debería ser catalogada como tal.

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que en general sí tienen sentido, y concretamente la pregunta que nos ocupa tal y como está formulada ahora me parece apropiada. Las ediciones han corregido la posible confusión inicial.